# Identify all distinct variables within party ctree nodel

Tags: r, tree, party

I am using ctree function within party R package. I would like to idenfiy all predictors that are used within the tree in order to reduce the data.frame dimension used for further analyses. For example:

```
library(ctree)
data(ozone)
myModel<-ctree(Ozone~., data=na.omit(airquality))
plot(myModel)
```

I would like a function receiving myModel and returning Temp, Wind and Ozone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this:

```
getUsefulPredictors<-function(x){
  flatTree<-unlist(x@tree)
  pred<-unique(flatTree[grepl("*variableName",names(flatTree))])
  return(pred)
}
```

It flattens the trees and looks for the elements having `variableName` in their name

Run on your model it returns:

```
getUsefulPredictors(myModel)
#[1] "Temp" "Wind"
```

Answer (score 4):

Just for completeness: The answer by NicE pertains to the `ctree()` implementation in the `party` package. If someone wants to do the same thing based on the new (and recommended) implementation in the `partykit` package, then a different function is necessary because the internal representation completely changed.

```
getUsefulPredictors <- function(x) {
  varid <- nodeapply(x, ids = nodeids(x),
    FUN = function(n) split_node(n)$varid)
  varid <- unique(unlist(varid))
  names(data_party(x))[varid]
}
```

This first obtains the variable ID `varid` from each split in each node of the tree. Then the names of the model frame are obtained and those pertaining to the unique variable IDs returned. In your example:

```
library("partykit")
myModel <- ctree(Ozone ~ ., data = na.omit(airquality))
getUsefulPredictors(myModel)    
## [1] "Temp" "Wind"
```